# asp.net using switch case in c# for datetime.now.hour format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, switch-statement

I created this asp.net program using switch case statement to determine the current datetime.now.hour in C#. When I compile it nothing happens, not even error comments.
I believe that I close to getting it to work, but I need to be pointed in the right direction. I'd appreciate any helpful suggestions. I believe my problem is not knowing exactly how to correctly convert the variable to the right data type. I'm really new to asp.net and I'm learning c# as I practice. I've got some experience in C++. Here is my code.

```
  <% Page Language="C#"%>
 <script runat="server">
 void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 int h= Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");
 switch (h)
 {
 case (h>12): lblMsg.Text="One O'clock!"; break;
 case (h>12): lblMsg.Text="Two O'clock!"; break;
 case (h>12): lblMsg.Text="Three O'clock!"; break;
 case (h>12): lblMsg.Text="Four O'clock!"; break;
 case (h>12): lblMsg.Text="Five O'clock!"; break;
 case (h>12): lblMsg.Text="Six O'clock!"; break;
 case (h>12): lblMsg.Text="Seven O'clock!"; break;
 case (h>12): lblMsg.Text="Eight O'clock!"; break;
 case (H>12): lblMsg.Text="Nine O'clock!"; break;
 case (H>12): lblMsg.Text="Ten O'clock!"; break;
 case (H>12): lblMsg.Text="Eleven O'clock!"; break;
 default: lblMsg.Text="Twelve O'clock!"; break;
 }
 }
 <script>
 <!doctype html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <asp:Label id="lb1Msg" runat="server" />
 <html>
```

Comment: you could do switch(true) and leave the rest as it is since the expressions will return bool (h > 12 it's either true or false) but in your case i don't think it would make any sense... just do case 1, case 2 ..... case 24.

Comment: Note that the [HH format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) gives a value (string) from "00" to "23".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each *case* label specifies a constant value. The *switch* statement transfers control to the *switch* section whose **case** label matches the value of the *switch* expression. If no **case** label contains a matching value, control is transferred to the *default* section, if there is one. If there is no *default* section, no action is taken and control is transferred outside the *switch* statement.

```
switch (h)
{
    case 1: lblMsg.Text="One O'clock!"; break;
    case 2: lblMsg.Text="Two O'clock!"; break;
    case 3: lblMsg.Text="Three O'clock!"; break;
    case 4: lblMsg.Text="Four O'clock!"; break;
    case 5: lblMsg.Text="Five O'clock!"; break;
    case 6: lblMsg.Text="Six O'clock!"; break;
    case 7: lblMsg.Text="Seven O'clock!"; break;
    case 8: lblMsg.Text="Eight O'clock!"; break;
    case 9: lblMsg.Text="Nine O'clock!"; break;
    case 10: lblMsg.Text="Ten O'clock!"; break;
    case 11: lblMsg.Text="Eleven O'clock!"; break;
    default: lblMsg.Text="Twelve O'clock!"; break;
}
```

You are using an expression with *case* while it's expecting **constants**.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for that. So the expression was (h>12), which might have been okay if I were using a if else statement. I made the correction but my code doesn't compile. I had a few errors. I'm trying to debug them now.